# Convenient constexpr-function

Tags: c++, constexpr

I can write a `constexpr` function that performs type deduction but does not use the object passed to it:

```
template <int N>
struct Foo
{
  static const int value = N;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr int get_value(T const &)
{
  return T::value;
}

void huey()
{
  Foo<3> three;
  static_assert(get_value(three) == 3, ":(");
}
```

However, if the argument to `get_value` is the result of some other operation, this approach fails:

```
template <int N>
Foo<N + 1> increase(Foo<N> const &)
{
  return {};
}

void dewey()
{
  Foo<6> six;
  static_assert(get_value(increase(six)) == 7, ":(");
}
```

The compiler (rightfully) complains that `increase(six)` is not a constant expression. I can fix this like this:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr int get_value2()
{
  return T::value;
}

void louie()
{
  Foo<4> four;
  static_assert(get_value2<decltype(increase(four))>() == 5, ":(");
}
```

but I do not like the extra `decltype`-gymnastics. I could introduce a macro:

```
#define GET_VALUE(x) get_value2<decltype(x)>()
```

but I would like to avoid macros, if possible. Is there any way to allow the convenient syntax `get_value(some_function(some_object))` without macros?

Comment: What is wrong with `template <int N> constexpr Foo<N + 1> increase(Foo<N> const &)` ?

Answer (score 1):

`increase()` needs to be `constexpr` too

```
template <int N>
struct Foo
{
    static const int value = N;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr int get_value(T const &)
{
    return T::value;
}

void huey()
{
    Foo<3> three;
    static_assert(get_value(three) == 3, ":(");
}

template <int N>
constexpr Foo<N + 1> increase(Foo<N> const &)
{
    return {};
}

void dewey()
{
    Foo<6> six;
    static_assert(get_value(increase(six)) == 7, ":(");
}
```